# PHP Display Special Characters

Tags: php

When i output the text **£3.99 per M²** from an xml file,browser displays
it as **Â£3.99 per MÂ²**.XML file is in UTF-8 format.I wonder how to fix
this.

Comment: Is the input XML correctly encoded?

Comment: Check the menu of your browser. All browsers have a setting where you can specify the encoding. Change it to UTF-8 and your browser should display it fine.

Comment: My browser set to utf-8.But no luck

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you're outputting UTF-8. That conversion sounds like your source is UTF-8, yet you're telling the browser to expect something else (Latin1?). You should send a header indicating to the browser UTF-8 is coming up, and you should have the correct meta header:

```
 <?php
 header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo "£3.99 per M²"; ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This should work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You should encode html entities:

you could try

```
htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) for a complete reference

If you still have problems sometimes you also have to decode the string with utf8_decode()
so you can try:

```
$str = utf8_decode($str);
$str = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: If the XML is actually encoded in UTF-8, this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: No, he shouldn't. He should only set up correct charset for page, see answer of Berry Langerak.

Comment: I don't think that encoding html entities is a bad practice, i've always problem with UTF-8  encoding and the only things that work usually is decode+htmlentities.

Comment: @Nicola, then make sure you use the correct headers as per my answer ;)

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti, it's mean usually you do useless work with it, and answer of Berry will be useful for you too.

Comment: I sure will, encoding always drives me mad!:)

Comment: @Nicola: XML is not HTML. You can not just create HTML entities within XML, the parser will see them as undefined entities and errors them.

Comment: @hakre i just meant to convert them when i output them to the browser. The XML is the source not the output

Comment: @Nicola: Now I see. But well, while taking a look into your code, your first converting the string form UTF-8 to latin-1 but then you made the mistake to use the entities replacement function with the UTF-8 encoding instead of the latin-1 encoding. I think you mixed something. First replace the chars with the entities, then change the encoding (to latin-1 or us-ascii).

Comment: @hakre yes you are right, i just copied from above and i hadn't thought about that!

Comment: Please read this to see what `utf8_decode` actually does: http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: I read that article two weeks ago, which is 2 months after this post! :)

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti, had tried a lot, but this one works..Thanks man !