# How to set charset to UTF-8 in a Zend application?

Tags: database, zend-framework, utf-8, character-encoding

I am developping a Zend application. The data in my database is encoded in "utf8_unicode_ci".
I declared in my application.ini :

```
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

but whenever I try to retrieve a String containing special characters like

{'é', 'à', 'è',...} in the db, the string doesn't display unless I use the function : `utf8_decode()`

So I tried to set the charset to UTF-8 in :

Bootstrap :

```
protected function _initDoctype() {
      $this->bootstrap('view');
      $view = $this->getResource('view');
      $view->doctype('XHTML_STRICT');
      $view->setEncoding('UTF-8');
 }

 protected function _initFrontControllerOutput() {

    $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
    $frontController = $this->getResource('FrontController');

    $response = new Zend_Controller_Response_Http;
    $response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', true);
    $frontController->setResponse($response);

    $frontController->setParam('useDefaultControllerAlways', false);

    return $frontController;
}
```

Layout :

```
$this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf8');
echo $this->headMeta();
```

application.ini :

```
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
```

EDIT : Now I can display special chars in a page, but when I retrieve elements from the database, special chars are not displayed.

- an escaped string returns `null` (`$this->escape($string)`)
- `echo $string` substitutes special chars with `?`

so I still have to use `utf8_decode()` to display them. Any suggestion ?

thanks for your help !!

Comment: By the way, my source files encoding is set to utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try to edit your source files keeping UTF-8 as your editor's encoding. Sometimes even if you use UTF-8 in your HTML headers, database encoding, etc, if your source files are in a different encoding, this could lead to that kind of errors.

Comment: All my source files are encoded in UTF-8, but although I did set headers, when I display some pages, none of them contains the charset tag in the headers

Comment: could it be that your browser's cache is causing this? In example, Google Chrome's Cache is really powerfull, and if you don't keep clearing cache while developing in a web page's view, you could get this problem. I'm not really sure if this happens in firefox too, I use firebug and keep cache disabled all the time.

Comment: I already solved this issue, this was indeed due to the database and the browser cache

Answer (score 16):

Have you set the following, to fetch data from MySQL as utf8?

```
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
```

It is necessary to do three things to get correct characters displaying correctly:

1. Save PHP/HTML files in utf8 encoding
2. Fetch data from MySQL as utf8
3. Send the right content-type / charset header or use a meta tag

Further information in [Rob Allen's article](http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/).

Comment: Indeed I didn't add this resource in the config file. Now my whole application is set to UTF-8, but although I added a `code`header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`code` the <meta> doesn't appear in the source code when I display the page

Comment: header and meta are two different things. To get the meta in your html, you need to add echo $this->headMeta(); in your layout script.

Comment: You can either set the header (or have Apache set it for you) or add the meta tag as Maxence describes. You don't need both the header AND the meta tag, but it won't hurt and the meta tag will serve as a backup.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem while using the Doctrine2 module in my Zend Framework 2 application. Explicitly setting the character set for my Doctrine2 module solved the issue...

Just add `'charset'  => 'utf8'` to your doctrine connection parameters:

```
'params' => array(
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'port'     => 'yourport',
    'user'     => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'dbname'   => 'yourdatabase',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
)
```

Might also work for your normal database connection. Add `'charset=utf8'` to the connection string:

```
'db' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => 'mysql:host=$localhost;dbname=$yourdatabase;charset=utf8',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    )
),
```

Comment: Adding charset=utf8 on dsn and 'charset' => 'utf8' at params works for me. Best answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried also setting the headers to utf8? Usually in php i do it this way

```
 header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

in your case i think you must use something different. i've taken this example from [Zend Framework documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.response.html) maybe you should use something different, i'm no expert of Zend_Framework

```
// Within an action controller action:
// Set a header
$this->getResponse()
    ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    ->appendBody($content);
```

If you set headers, meta and encoding it should work (from your code it seems to me you are only setting meta and encoding)

(look at this question to understand what i mean, the answer from Berry Langerak: [PHP Display Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264049/php-display-special-characters/6264073#6264073))

EDIT - i also found another example in this article where it sets the header for a controller, take a look at it,maybe this is what you are looking for : http://www.chris.lu/en/news/show/4d56d0ecb058c/

This part might be what you are looking for:

```
protected function _initFrontControllerOutput() {

    $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
    $frontController = $this->getResource('FrontController');

    $response = new Zend_Controller_Response_Http;
    $response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', true);
    $frontController->setResponse($response);

    $frontController->setParam('useDefaultControllerAlways', false);

    return $frontController;

}
```

Comment: I already have set the headers to utf8 with this line in my layout file :
this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf8'); but I also tried your function header with returns "Header() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in....

Comment: Thank you for the link (chris.lu), but I tried to place thi
s function into my bootstrap and it doesn't change anything

Comment: no i think that with that line you only set the "meta": that means the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in the html. If you see the other question i linked, they set the meta and the headers, but i don't know exactly how to set headers in Zend

Comment: This answer is good, but setting the response in that way breaks unit tests in PHPUnit

Answer (score 1):

as others said we have to set the encoding, in my Zend framework I had to do it in little different way:

1. in db.ini file:

**charset = "utf8"**

```
adapter = PDO_MYSQL
dbname = skydevel_skydevfinal
username = root
password = 
hostname = localhost
sprofiler = false
charset = "utf8"
```

add this line below where you declared the database, username, etc.

2.Now in bootstrap.php file point the reference to that new line:

**'charset'=>$dbConfig->charset**

```
end_Db::factory($dbConfig->adapter, array('host' => $dbConfig->host,
                'username' => $dbConfig->username,
                'password' => $dbConfig->password,
                'dbname' => $dbConfig->dbname,
                'charset'=>$dbConfig->charset
```

3. you have to set your database and table to UTF-8, here is how I have done:
   `ALTER DATABASE skydevel_skydevfinal CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
   ALTER TABLE ch_news_comments CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use utf8_encode() it's meaning that the data in your database is not encoded in UTF8.
When you say that your database is encoded in "utf8_unicode_ci" it doesn't actually mean that your data is encoded in UTF8.

To verify that set encoding is working with Zend Framework by using any of the code you show, it's quite easy. With firefox just right click on the page and click on "View page info" if it's say "Encoding: UTF8" it means that your page is correctly encoded but that your data is not.

If you was using utf8_decode(), then it would mean that Zend is failing to set the encoding.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake I use utf8_decode() to display data, however, when I check the page info, the charset is set to UTF-8

Comment: That is definitely really weird... utf8_decode() decode to ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 0):

If you put all the codification and collation like 'utf8_general_ci' in the BD and then in the application.ini just next of mysql connection parameters, `resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i fixed it in config/autoload/global.php 
by setting charset value :

```
'db' => [
    'adapters' => [
        'dummy' => [],
        'myadapter' => ['charset'  => 'utf-8',],
    ],
```

Answer (score -1):

I used to develop ZF application with many languages including RTL ones .
and I used to add this to my bootstrap file and I've found it pretty neat .

**maybe this not an answer but i think its good suggestion** :

```
public function _initMB(){
 mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
}
```

for more info about `mb_internal_string` check out : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

Comment: Thank you, I added this function, but it doesn't seem to work either