# Apache ignores meta charset on HTML display in browser

Tags: php, apache, encoding, ascii, zend-framework

I have problem with meta charset encoding. I have a Zend App which inserts the meta charset into phtml file this way:

```
$this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$this->headMeta();
```

In browser, the page has set the us-ascii charset. I don't know why it's happening.
Apache and PHP conf files have set charset with UTF-8 encoding.
My local server is set on Linux Mint (on VirtualBox in Windows 7). File encoding conversion doesn't change anything.

===============
The problem occured because of php5-tidy Apache module.

Comment: Check Apache config for "AddDefaultCharset" setting. If this is set this will override any meta settings.

Comment: Have you verified the *generated* HTML tag ("View Source" menu in your browser) and the *generated* HTTP header ("Net" panel in Firebug or whatever tool you use)?

Comment: it seems that there is a problem with Apache2 server. It changes the charset for content for PHP files only. It's not a problem with Zend.

Answer (score 0):

Take look here: [How to set charset to UTF-8 in a Zend application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276150/how-to-set-charset-to-utf-8-in-a-zend-application) .Make sure your working files are saved with utf-8 encoding.