# Doctrine 1.2 query with utf8 column name

Tags: mysql, utf-8, non-ascii-characters, doctrine-1.2

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635627/doctrine-query-with-utf8-column-name) same problem, but with Doctrine 1.2 instead of Doctrine 2.0.

I have a column with non-Ascii character in his name, and Doctrine give me this error when I try to select it :

> Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '??_avanc?? AS c4__1 (...)

Where there should be the french "é" char instead of the double questions marks.

Here is my connection :

```
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection("mysql://username:password@locahost/mydb","my_connection");
$conn->setCollate('utf8_general_ci');
$conn->setCharset("utf8");
```

And here is my select :

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()->select("vicl_relevé_avancé vc")->FROM("vc.VisiteClient")->where("vc.id = ?", $id)->execute();
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

*Double* question marks?  Ouch.  That probably implies that multiple things are going wrong.

The table/column needs to be `CHARACTER SET utf8`; see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to check on that.  Fixing that *may* fix the problem, but it may just make it different.

`SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...` -- to see what is actually stored.  `latin1` will show E9 for é; `utf8` will show C3A9 for é.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE visite_client (
 id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
(...)
 vicl_relevé_avancé enum('','demandé','fait','pas fait') NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=147282 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` But the problem is not with the content of the field, but with its name...

Comment: Ah.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

Comment: `character_set_client utf8
character_set_connection utf8
character_set_database utf8
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results utf8
character_set_server latin1
character_set_system utf8
character_sets_dir /usr/share/mysql/charsets/`

Comment: I must precise that I don't have this problem outside of Doctrine. If a I use PhpMyAdmin, or CodeIgniter orm, there is no error

Comment: I know nothing about Doctrine (other than it seems to get in the way); dig through it to see what character settings it has in its config/init/connection/whatever.