# Doctrine ORM AnnotationReader unable to parse annotations if the comment field contains an accented character (é, è, ...)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have about 50 classes defined as Doctrine entities.

After upgrading to PHP 7.4, Doctrine returned errors like this for every entity:

```
class "Site\Entities\MyEntity" sub class of "Repo\Entity" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

However both classes had the correct annotations, but debugging showed me that Doctrine's `AnnotationReader` failed to get the annotations from my `MyEntity` class.

After debugging for some time I finally found the source of the problem:

```
/**
 * class my_entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="....")
 *
 * @author John La classe hérite de \Repo\Entity
 */
```

`AnnotationReader` was unable to read the annotations `Entity` and `Table` because of the accented character in `hérite`. By changing it to a normal `e`, `AnnotationReader` works as intended

However this comment is almost everywhere in my project's Composer dependencies so changing it everywhere is going to be tedious.

Is this issue known to anyone? Is there a setting I can change in Doctrine to fix this? I have been unable to find information on either GitHub or the internet at large regarding this

Comment: Its not tedious at all, what IDE are you using?

Comment: Ideally I would like to avoid it @Skip, our internal process will require a lot of PRs to be opened, and it will be a pain to manage that on top of already existing PRs. Although I may as well do it since it seems there isn't a fix...

Comment: I found something that might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33691400/13149335

Comment: If you replace the pattern that caches è with \w in the Lexer.php it shouldn't throw an error

Comment: That didn't work, however switching the file encoding to UTF-8 for all of my entities did help.