# PHP issue with diacritics

Tags: php, html, diacritics

I have thi code for read files from folder:

```
<?php
$directory = "Dokumenty/rozne";
$a = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));
$i = 1;
foreach($a as $key => $name){
    $link = "http://mana.fara.sk/Dokumenty/rozne/" . $name;
    echo  "<p>$i: <a href='$link' >$name</a></p><br>";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

but on the webpage diacritics is displayed incorrectly: here is example
Pamiatkovy���� vyskum.docx

Can you help me how to selve this problem?.... In head a have   `<meta charset="UTF-8">` and html lang is `lang="sk-SK"`

THX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Display Special Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264049/php-display-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because `scandir` return a non-UTF-8 string. You should either update your file names with the right encoding, or convert the string's encoding to UTF-8. Windows should use ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252.

So, you can try with:

```
$name = iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $name);
```